# what is invoking?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, invoke

What is method invoke, control.invoke?

What is invoking in general in programming

examples :

```
MethodInvoker getValues = new MethodInvoker(delegate()
{
    checkbox1Checked = checkbox1.Checked;
    textBox6Text = textBox6.Text;
    textBox7Text = textBox7.Text;
    textBox3Text = textBox3.Text;
    textBox1Text = textBox1.Text;
    textBox4Text = textBox4.Text;
    richTextBox1Text = richTextBox1.Text;
    textBox5Text = textBox5.Text;
});

if (this.InvokeRequired)
{
    this.Invoke(getValues);
}
else
{
    getValues();
}
```

And I also wanna know what does MethodInvoker and InvokeRequired mean?

Comment: See very good answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14703698/c-invokedelegate

Answer (score 15):

“Invoking” refers to calling a method.

In winforms `Control.Invoke` is used to call a method on the UI thread — without it you can cause an exception by updating the UI from another thread.

And so if `InvokeRequires` returns `true` it means that you are not running in the UI thread and should use `Control.Invoke` to run the call in the right thread.

Comment: Also, you might want to use asynchronous version - `BeginInvoke`