# Invoke(Delegate)

Tags: c#, winforms, delegates, invoke

Can anybody please explain this statement written on this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.invoke.aspx)

```
Invoke(Delegate):
```

Executes the specified delegate on the thread that owns the **control's underlying window handle.**

Can anybody explain what this means (especially the bold one) I am not able to get it clearly

Comment: The answer to this question is tied to the Control.InvokeRequired property - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.invokerequired%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Answer (score 146, accepted):

The answer to this question lies in how C# Controls work

> Controls in Windows Forms are bound to a specific thread and are not
>   thread safe. Therefore, if you are calling a control's method from a
>   different thread, you must use one of the control's invoke methods to
>   marshal the call to the proper thread. This property can be used to
>   determine if you must call an invoke method, which can be useful if
>   you do not know what thread owns a control.

From [Control.InvokeRequired](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.invokerequired%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Effectively, what Invoke does is ensure that the code you are calling occurs on the thread that the control "lives on" effectively preventing cross threaded exceptions.

From a historical perspective, in .Net 1.1, this was actually allowed. What it meant is that you could try and execute code on the "GUI" thread from any background thread and this would mostly work. Sometimes it would just cause your app to exit because you were effectively interrupting the GUI thread while it was doing something else. This is the *Cross Threaded Exception* - imagine trying to update a TextBox while the GUI is painting something else.

- Which action takes priority?
- Is it even possible for both to happen at once?
- What happens to all of the other commands the GUI needs to run?

Effectively, you are interrupting a queue, which can have lots of unforeseen consequences. Invoke is effectively the "polite" way of getting what you want to do into that queue, and this rule was enforced from .Net 2.0 onward via a thrown [InvalidOperationException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.invalidoperationexception.aspx).

To understand what is actually going on behind the scenes, and what is meant by "GUI Thread", it's useful to understand what a Message Pump or Message Loop is.

This is actually already answered in the question "[What is a Message Pump](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2222365/what-is-a-message-pump)" and is recommended reading for understanding the actual mechanism that you are tying into when interacting with controls.

Other reading you may find useful includes:

[What's up with Begin Invoke](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10311/What-s-up-with-BeginInvoke)

> One of the cardinal rules of Windows GUI programming is that only the
>   thread that created a control can access and/or modify its contents
>   (except for a few documented exceptions). Try doing it from any other
>   thread and you'll get unpredictable behavior ranging from deadlock, to
>   exceptions to a half updated UI. The right way then to update a
>   control from another thread is to post an appropriate message to the
>   application message queue. When the message pump gets around to
>   executing that message, the control will get updated, on the same
>   thread that created it (remember, the message pump runs on the main
>   thread).

and, for a more code heavy overview with a representative sample:

[Invalid Cross-thread Operations](http://www.perceler.com/articles1.php?art=crossthreads1)

```
// the canonical form (C# consumer)

public delegate void ControlStringConsumer(Control control, string text);  // defines a delegate type

public void SetText(Control control, string text) {
    if (control.InvokeRequired) {
        control.Invoke(new ControlStringConsumer(SetText), new object[]{control, text});  // invoking itself
    } else {
        control.Text=text;      // the "functional part", executing only on the main thread
    }
}
```

Once you have an appreciation for InvokeRequired, you may wish to consider using an extension method for wrapping these calls up. This is ably covered in the Stack Overflow question [Cleaning Up Code Littered with Invoke Required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3874134/cleaning-up-code-littered-with-invokerequired).

There is also a further [write up of what happened historically](http://ikriv.com/dev/dotnet/MysteriousHang.html) that may be of interest.

Answer (score 79):

A control or window object in Windows Forms is just a wrapper around a Win32 window identified by a *handle* (sometimes called HWND). Most things you do with the control will eventually result in a Win32 API call that uses this handle. The handle is owned by the thread that created it (typically the main thread), and shouldn't be manipulated by another thread. If for some reason you need to do something with the control from another thread, you can use `Invoke` to ask the main thread to do it on your behalf.

For instance, if you want to change the text of a label from a worker thread, you can do something like this:

```
theLabel.Invoke(new Action(() => theLabel.Text = "hello world from worker thread!"));
```

Comment: Can you explain why someone would do something like this? `this.Invoke(() => this.Enabled = true);` Whatever `this` refers to is surely in the current thread, right?

Comment: @KyleDelaney, an object isn't "in" a thread, and the current thread isn't necessarily the thread that created the object.

Answer (score 34):

If you want to modify a control it must be done in the thread in which the control was created. This `Invoke` method allows you to execute methods in the associated thread (the thread that owns the control's underlying window handle).

In below sample thread1 throws an exception because SetText1 is trying to modify textBox1.Text from another thread. But in thread2, Action in SetText2 is executed in the thread in which the TextBox was created

```
private void btn_Click(object sender, EvenetArgs e)
{
    var thread1 = new Thread(SetText1);
    var thread2 = new Thread(SetText2);
    thread1.Start();
    thread2.Start();
}

private void SetText1() 
{
    textBox1.Text = "Test";
}

private void SetText2() 
{
    textBox1.Invoke(new Action(() => textBox1.Text = "Test"));
}
```

Comment: I really like this approach, it hides delegates nature, but it's nice shortcut anyway.

Comment: Thanks for a succinct example that does exactly what I need.

Answer (score 9):

```
Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate{ textBox1.Text = "Test"; });
```

Comment: The use of System.Action people suggest on other responses only works on framework 3.5+, for older versions, this works perfectly

Answer (score 3):

In practical terms it means that the delegate is guaranteed to be invoked on the main thread. This is important because in the case of windows controls if you don't update their properties on the main thread then you either don't see the change, or the control raises an exception.

The pattern is:

```
void OnEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (this.InvokeRequired)
   {
       this.Invoke(() => this.OnEvent(sender, e);
       return;
   }

   // do stuff (now you know you are on the main thread)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`this.Invoke(delegate)` make sure that you are calling the delegate the argument to `this.Invoke()` on main thread/created thread.

I can say a Thumb rule don't access your form controls except from main thread.

May be the following lines make sense for using Invoke()

```
    private void SetText(string text)
    {
        // InvokeRequired required compares the thread ID of the
        // calling thread to the thread ID of the creating thread.
        // If these threads are different, it returns true.
        if (this.textBox1.InvokeRequired)
        {   
            SetTextCallback d = new SetTextCallback(SetText);
            this.Invoke(d, new object[] { text });
        }
        else
        {
            this.textBox1.Text = text;
        }
    }
```

There are situations though you create a Threadpool thread(i.e worker thread) it will run on main thread. It won't create a new thread coz main thread is available for processing further instructions. So First investigate whether the current running thread is main thread using `this.InvokeRequired` if returns true the current code is running on worker thread so call 
    this.Invoke(d, new object[] { text });

else directly update the UI control(Here you are guaranteed that you are running the code on main thread.)

Comment: Thanks for the example of how to use InvokeRequired on a control.

Answer (score 2):

It means that the delegate will run on the UI thread, even if you call that method from a background worker or thread-pool thread. UI elements have *thread affinity* - they only like talking directly to one thread: the UI thread. The UI thread is *defined as* the thread that created the control instance, and is therefore associated with the window handle. But all of that is an implementation detail.

The key point is: you would call this method from a worker thread so that you can access the UI (to change the value in a label, etc) - since you are ***not allowed*** to do that from any other thread than the UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

Delegate are essentially inline `Action`'s or `Func<T>`. You can declare a delegate outside the scope of a method which you are running or using a `lambda` expression(`=>`); because you run the delegate within a method, you run it on the thread which is being run for the current window/application which is the bit in bold.

**Lambda example**

```
int AddFiveToNumber(int number)
{
  var d = (int i => i + 5);
  d.Invoke(number);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It means that the delegate you pass is executed on the thread that created the Control object (which is the UI thread).

You need to call this method when your application is multi-threaded and you want do some UI operation from a thread other than the UI thread, because if you just try to call a method on a Control from a different thread you'll get a System.InvalidOperationException.