# unexpected system exception while trying not to rewrite a file and saving it in new location in C#

Tags: c#, exception, save-as

I use a savefiledialog in the application to save the file. If the same filename already exists I get a popup asking if i want to replace or not. If i give **no** I get unexpected system exception. Below is part of code

```
string fname1 = "";

saveFileDialog.Title = "Save the Proofer Report";
saveFileDialog.Filter = "Excel Files (*.xls)|*.xls";
saveFileDialog.FilterIndex = 0;
saveFileDialog.InitialDirectory = "MyDocuments";
saveFileDialog.FileName = "Proofer Report";
aveFileDialog.AddExtension = true;
saveFileDialog.ShowHelp = true;

// saveFileDialog.ShowDialog();

Invoke((Action)(() => { saveFileDialog.ShowDialog(); }));
fname1 = saveFileDialog.FileName;


                xlWorkBook.SaveAs(fname1, Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal,       misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);
 //system exception during save as
                xlWorkBook.Close(true, misValue, misValue);
                xlApp.Quit();
```

stack trace

> at Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Workbook.SaveAs(Object Filename,
>   Object FileFormat, Object Password, Object WriteResPassword, Object
>   ReadOnlyRecommended, Object CreateBackup, XlSaveAsAccessMode
>   AccessMode, Object ConflictResolution, Object AddToMru, Object
>   TextCodepage, Object TextVisualLayout, Object Local)    at
>   ProoferXML.MainForm.ProcessDocument(BackgroundWorker worker,
>   DoWorkEventArgs e) in
>   D:\ProoferXML\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\MainForm.cs:line
>   665    at ProoferXML.MainForm.prooferWorker_DoWork(Object sender,
>   DoWorkEventArgs e) in
>   D:\ProoferXML\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\MainForm.cs:line
>   1457

While Saving the excel using workbook.saveAs getting the Exception from HRESULT:

Comment: can we see full code (with saving)? and what type of the exception?

Comment: please post your exception

Comment: show us the exception you are getting and line on which you are getting the exception

Comment: We can't tell which line is line number 1,457.

Comment: xlWorkBook.SaveAs(fname1, Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal,       misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);
 //system exception during save as

Comment: try saving the file at that location with different name

Comment: it works if i give a different name.but if i try to replace it thn its throwing error.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you have to pay attention to threading model you are using. It is recommended to check InvokeRequired before calling Invoke. 
So your code should look like:

```
 if (InvokeRequired)
 {
   Invoke((Action)(() => { saveFileDialog.ShowDialog(); }));
 }
 else
 {
   saveFileDialog.ShowDialog();
 }
```

Some more useful reading Invoke [Invoke(Delegate)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14703698/c-invokedelegate)

Comment: Am getting error during save as ---
xlWorkBook.SaveAs(fname1, Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue)

Comment: While Saving the excel using workbook.saveAs getting the Exception from HRESULT:

Comment: you may try to use Application.DisplayAlerts = false;
before calling SaveAs to prevent overwrite warning generating by Excel.