# Unity3d Access main thread from timer

Tags: c#, multithreading, unity-game-engine, timer

When trying to access a gameobjects position from a timer like this:

```
public static void Start()
{
    if(!timerStarted)
    {
        timerStarted = true;
        timer = new Timer();
        timer.Interval = 1000;

        timer.Elapsed += CheckEarnings;
        timer.AutoReset = true;
        timer.Enabled = true;
    }            
}

private static void CheckEarnings(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (BuildingData building in BuildingRegistry.registeredBuildings)
    {
        MonoBehaviour.print(building.attachedGameObject.transform.position);
    }
}
```

(In a Static Class if this makes any difference)

...The following Error is thrown:

> get_transform can only be called from the main thread.
>   Constructors and field initializers will be executed from the loading thread when loading a scene.
>   Don't use this function in the constructor or field initializers, instead move initialization code to the Awake or Start function.
>   UnityEngine.GameObject:get_transform()
>   PlayerManagement:CheckEarnings(Object, ElapsedEventArgs) (at Assets/Scripts/PlayerManagement.cs:53)
>   System.Timers.Timer:Callback(Object)

For me it looks like there is another thread created for the timer which can't access the main thread.
How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Rather than fixing your problem, try to google about using timers in unity: [click](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/351420/simple-timer-1.html), [click](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/225213/c-countdown-timer.html), [click](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/940197/c-simple-timer.html) ...

Comment: I was searching for a Solution for the System.Timers Timer but thats also a possibility.

Comment: You can use `System.Timers` for this. See the link in the duplicate for how to call unity function from another thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct in assuming that the issue is the timer is running on a seperate thread, that said there are many different solutions to this. I assume based on your syntax that you are using [`System.Timers.Timer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer(v=vs.110).aspx), this in your instance means that the timer runs the elapsed event on a [`ThreadPool`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3dasc8as(v=vs.80).aspx).

If you are intent on using the C# timers rather than creating your own timer using `Time.deltaTime` then the issue becomes how to use the UnityAPI on a seperate thread, the simple truth is that you can't. Unity is thread safe by design and thus you must create a system for running functions on the main thread by creating a list of [Delegates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8(v=vs.110).aspx) and then on the main thread running through that list executing them all.

The simplest solution though would be to simply store a float value of total time elapsed and every frame increase it by `Time.deltaTime`, the float value will represent the seconds passed and you can quite easily call functions based on that value.

Answer (score 0):

Originally there was no protection against cross threading operations. The end results were less then optimal and often non-deterministic. So the CrossThreadExceptions were added. The proper way to avoid them is to [invoke](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14703806). However my knowledge is about C# .NET, not Unity. And in Unity stuff might be named differntly.

Note that different 'Timer' classes can have totally different behavior. i.e., .NET Actually as no less then 4 'Timer' classes whose behaviors could not be more different. When writing this article explaining them it was only 3:
https://web.archive.org/web/20150329101415/https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164015.aspx

Comment: I thought Invoke exclusively for Winform applications? That's what I thought at least, hence why I did not mention it in my answer.