# Calling a method to run in the background that still lets the user work in the form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

In my main class, I have a list of objects with a DateTime data member. I also have a method that loops through that list and checks its members against the current DateTime. I know I can use a Timer to call that method every interval. However, the method will be called very frequently (i.e. the interval is very short), and would block the user from doing anything else. I want the user to be able to interact with the form while the method is running in the background. However, if the method finds a match in its loop, I want the form to create another error-message form and stop anything else from happening until it's dealt with. What I need to know is how to get the method to be constantly called in the background, AND have it jump to the foreground and stop everything else if a specific thing happens.

Comment: Background worker component

Comment: This is what [async / await](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14455293/how-and-when-to-use-async-and-await) were made for.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [backgroundworker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker(v=vs.110).aspx).

You can get the results on completion and you can also get results in the reports progress event.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use some form of Multitasking to do this.

As a beginner and working in Windows Forms, I usually advice for BackgroundWorker. That interuption is a bit tricky.

Working with the UI from another thread is [really tricky, however](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14703806). But I guess you could have the BGW's DoWork Event cancel (with an appropirate error message) and then display a modal Dialog (any form with ShowDialog() ) to block inputs from the RunWorkerCompleted Event.

Comment: But you don't have to update the UI from another thread.  Can use the competed or report progress events.

Comment: @paparazzo: That is why I said to put that Modal Dialog into the RunWorkerCompleted Event.

Answer (score 0):

Asynchronous approach will help

```
private async Task DoJob()
{
    while (true) // or loop through DateTime values
    {
        await Task.Delay(1000): // 1 second
        if (DateTime.Now == dateTimeValue)
        {
            using (var form = new ErrorForm())
            {
                form.ShowDialog();
            }
        }

        // Possible condition for exit from while loop
    }
}
```

With async-await execution will remain on the main thread, which give you possibility to show error message without problems of accessing UI from different thread.