# Live updating chart with Vimba API

Tags: c#, camera

I am working with a vimba camera, and I am trying to set up a histogram that gets updated on every frame incoming from the camera, in order to detect saturation of pixels (color value = 255). Incomming frames from the camera are placed in bitmaps with `PixelFormat = fromat8bppIndexed` (grayscale) at a 15-20 FPS rate.

The way my histogram works is the following : I lock bits from a bitmap, sweeps across the image, retrieve the colour info for each pixel, and increments the corresponding index in an array (ex : if a pixel has got a color intensity of 126, I increment array[126] by one). At the end of the sweep, I have an array[256], and each of its value corresponds to the number of pixels with that particular color intensity. I then just have to draw my histogram using the array index as X, and the array values as y. I tested the code on random bitmaps (not from the camera), and it works perfectly.

The histogram code is placed inside the `OnFrameReceived(Frame)` function from the Vimba API, which use is the following : "Event will be triggered when a Frame buffer is filled with data" (from Vimba API manual). I know there is no problem with the delegate because part of the code inside the function works perfectly.

I had written a previous version of the code using `GetPixels`, but I read that it was a very slow way to retrieve data from an image, so I switched to using `LockBits` instead. I know I got the syntax right because I tested it outside of the `OnFrameReceived`function, and it works (way faster than `GetPixels`).

Now my problem is that, when I start the acquisition, the histogram doesn't fill with the data.

Here is the code :

```
    private void OnFrameReceived(Frame frame)
    {
        Bitmap myBitmap = null;
        if (true == m_Acquiring)
        {
            mycamera.QueueFrame(frame);
        }

        frame.Fill(ref myBitmap);
        pictureBoxLiveCamera.Image = myBitmap;
        SaveBitmap = myBitmap; //Up to here the code works perfectly, as I can use SaveBitmap correctly later in my program

        //Emptying chartInit
        Array.Clear(PixelColorCount, 0, 256);
        foreach (var Series in chartHist.Series)
        {
            Series.Points.Clear();
        }

        //Retrieving pixels data
        unsafe
        {
            int width = SaveBitmap.Width;
            int height = SaveBitmap.Height;
            int bytesPerPixel = 1;
            int maxPointerLength = width * height * bytesPerPixel;
            int stride = width * bytesPerPixel;
            System.Drawing.Imaging.BitmapData bData = SaveBitmap.LockBits(new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, SaveBitmap.Width, SaveBitmap.Height), System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, SaveBitmap.PixelFormat);
            byte* scan0 = (byte*)bData.Scan0.ToPointer();
            byte B;
            for (int i = 1; i < maxPointerLength; i++)
            {
                    B = scan0[i];
                    PixelColorCount[B] += 1;
            }
            SaveBitmap.UnlockBits(bData);
        }

        //Plotting the pixel counter, to detect saturation
        for (int i = 0; i < PixelColorCount.Length; i++)
        {
            chartHist.Series["Pixel count"].Points.AddXY(i, PixelColorCount[i]);
        }
    }
```

Does anyone have an idea what could be wrong with my code ? If nothing's wrong, could this have something to do with the computing time being to long and the frame being refreshed too fast ? How to check for this ? What could I do to fix it ?

Thanks !

EDIT : The call for the `OnFrameReceived`event is triggered on the Button Click event, here is the code with the handler :

```
            this.m_Acquiring = true;
            mycamera.OnFrameReceived += new Camera.OnFrameReceivedHandler(this.OnFrameReceived);
            mycamera.StartContinuousImageAcquisition(1);
```

I just did a few tests with breakdown points in the code, and it seems that the `Emptying chartInit` part runs (breakdown points reached), but the `foreach` loop runs indefinitely. This is probably the problem.

Comment: I can image that 20+ fps is a little too fast, but you still should see at least some data in the chart. What do you see when you set a breakpoint in the last loop? Are the data credible?

Comment: Also: I'm not really sure about the way you read the pixel data. I don't think there is a guaratee that how the palette is structured or even its size. You probably need to read it first and analyze it. But I never read 8bpp images, so I don't really know.

Comment: @TaW  So, if I put a breakdown in the last `for{}` loop and run the code, it doesn't seem to ever reach the breakpoint. Could that indicate that frames are changing too fast for the code to run properly ?

Comment: About the pixel reading method, I get the same result this way that with my old `GetPixel` code, so I guess it is fine.

Comment: Assuming PixelColorCount.Length is > 0, maybe. Do you ever hit the for loop itself? Also: Do add a little on how the event is called..

Comment: @TaW  It's done. I also added info about a few breakdown points tests I just did.

Comment: Hm, is there any kind of mulithreading involved?

Comment: I never knowingly activated this, and there is no mention of "threads" or "threading" in my code (I searched), so I guess no. I am fairly new with C# and coding as a whole, so I may be wrong.

Comment: You should check if you are on the main thread before updating any ui controls by [invoking](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14703806)