# UI hanging while I am using Threading C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

I am using threadpool method to do multi threading , in the same time the UI hanging do not know why , is there any solution for that. here is the snippet  code:

```
private void CommentThread(object obj)
{
    CancellationToken token = (CancellationToken)obj;

    RandomNumber = new Random();

    // ListViewItemCollection URLCOllection;
    if (UrlListview.InvokeRequired)
    {

        UrlListview.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
        {
           // URLCOllection = UrlListview.Items;
        foreach (ListViewItem item in UrlListview.Items)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(item.Text);
                Thread.Sleep(3000);
            }
            /*
            foreach (ListViewItem url in URLCOllection)
            {
                if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
                {
                    cts.Cancel();
                    return;

                }
                MessageBox.Show(url.Text);
                int delayamount = RandomNumber.Next(int.Parse(CommentsMinDelayNumric.Value.ToString()), int.Parse(CommentsMaxDelayNumric.Value.ToString()));
                Thread.Sleep(delayamount*1000);
            }



    }
        */


        }));
    }

    else
    {

        URLCOllection = UrlListview.Items;
    }
        foreach (string url in URLCOllection)
        {
            if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                cts.Cancel();
                return;

            }
            MessageBox.Show(url);
            int delayAmount = RandomNumber.Next(int.Parse(CommentsMinDelayNumric.Value.ToString()), int.Parse(CommentsMaxDelayNumric.Value.ToString()));
            Thread.Sleep(delayAmount * 1000);


        }





}
```

Comment: Dont sleep on the UI thread, the very definition of that is stall the ui

Comment: ok what kind of delay I can use ?

Comment: await Task.Delay(5000);?

Comment: When you Invoke() on a UI element you are running on the UI thread.

Comment: tried  Task.Delay(delayAmount).Wait();
but it didn't make any delay !

Comment: You need to understand what invoke does and why it is there, so you stop sleeping your GUI Thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14703806/3346583 Multitasking goes way beyond just single line Fixes in complexity.

Comment: Thanks for the link                         await Task.Delay(timetodelay*1000);
solved the issue !