# Forcing certain code to always run on the same thread

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, powershell, asp.net-web-api2

We have an old 3rd party system (let's call it Junksoft® 95) that we interface with via PowerShell (it exposes a COM object) and I'm in the process of wrapping it in a REST API (ASP.NET Framework 4.8 and WebAPI 2). I use the `System.Management.Automation` nuget package to create a `PowerShell` in which I instantiate Junksoft's COM API as a `dynamic` object that I then use:

```
//I'm omitting some exception handling and maintenance code for brevity
powerShell = System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.Create();
powerShell.AddScript("Add-Type -Path C:\Path\To\Junksoft\Scripting.dll");
powerShell.AddScript("New-Object Com.Junksoft.Scripting.ScriptingObject");
dynamic junksoftAPI = powerShell.Invoke()[0];

//Now we issue commands to junksoftAPI like this:
junksoftAPI.Login(user,pass);
int age = junksoftAPI.GetAgeByCustomerId(custId);
List<string> names = junksoftAPI.GetNames();
```

This works fine when I run all of this on the same thread (e.g. in a console application). However, for some reason this *usually* doesn't work when I put `junksoftAPI` into a `System.Web.Caching.Cache` and use it from different controllers in my web app. I say *ususally* because this actually works when ASP.NET happens to give the incoming call to the thread that `junksoftAPI` was created on. If it doesn't, Junksoft 95 gives me an error.

Is there any way for me to make sure that all interactions with `junksoftAPI` happen on the *same* thread?

**Note** that I don't want to turn the whole web application into a single-threaded application! The logic in the controllers and elswhere should happen like normal on different threads. It should only be the Junksoft interactions that happen on the Junksoft-specific thread, something like this:

```
[HttpGet]
public IHttpActionResult GetAge(...)
{
    //finding customer ID in database...

    ...

    int custAge = await Task.Run(() => {
        //this should happen on the Junksoft-specific thread and not the next available thread
        var cache = new System.Web.Caching.Cache();
        var junksoftAPI = cache.Get(...); //This has previously been added to cache on the Junksoft-specific thread
        return junksoftAPI.GetAgeByCustomerId(custId);
    });

    //prepare a response using custAge...
}
```

Comment: That behavior sounds a **lot** like the rules we enforced for GUI classes. Maybe their solution works as well? https://stackoverflow.com/a/14703806/3346583

Comment: For COM, you'll probably need pumping. So you'll need a separate STA thread to create it on and marshal all calls to that.

Comment: You say junksoft, but this is also useful for something like System.Printing.PrintQueue

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create your own singleton worker thread to achieve this. Here is the code which you can plug it into your web application.

```
public class JunkSoftRunner
{
    private static JunkSoftRunner _instance;

    //singleton pattern to restrict all the actions to be executed on a single thread only.
    public static JunkSoftRunner Instance => _instance ?? (_instance = new JunkSoftRunner());

    private readonly SemaphoreSlim _semaphore;
    private readonly AutoResetEvent _newTaskRunSignal;

    private TaskCompletionSource<object> _taskCompletionSource;
    private Func<object> _func;

    private JunkSoftRunner()
    {
        _semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(1, 1);
        _newTaskRunSignal = new AutoResetEvent(false);
        var contextThread = new Thread(ThreadLooper)
        {
            Priority = ThreadPriority.Highest
        };
        contextThread.Start();
    }

    private void ThreadLooper()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            //wait till the next task signal is received.
            _newTaskRunSignal.WaitOne();

            //next task execution signal is received.
            try
            {
                //try execute the task and get the result
                var result = _func.Invoke();

                //task executed successfully, set the result
                _taskCompletionSource.SetResult(result);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //task execution threw an exception, set the exception and continue with the looper
                _taskCompletionSource.SetException(ex);
            }

        }
    }

    public async Task<TResult> Run<TResult>(Func<TResult> func, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
    {
        //allows only one thread to run at a time.
        await _semaphore.WaitAsync(cancellationToken);

        //thread has acquired the semaphore and entered
        try
        {
            //create new task completion source to wait for func to get executed on the context thread
            _taskCompletionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();

            //set the function to be executed by the context thread
            _func = () => func();

            //signal the waiting context thread that it is time to execute the task
            _newTaskRunSignal.Set();

            //wait and return the result till the task execution is finished on the context/looper thread.
            return (TResult)await _taskCompletionSource.Task;
        }
        finally
        {
            //release the semaphore to allow other threads to acquire it.
            _semaphore.Release();
        }
    }
}
```

Console Main Method for testing:

```
public class Program
{
    //testing the junk soft runner
    public static void Main()
    {
        //get the singleton instance
        var softRunner = JunkSoftRunner.Instance;

        //simulate web request on different threads
        for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            var taskIndex = i;
            //launch a web request on a new thread.
            Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Task{taskIndex} (ThreadID:'{Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId})' Launched");
                return await softRunner.Run(() =>
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"->Task{taskIndex} Completed On '{Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}' thread.");
                    return taskIndex;
                });
            });
        }
    }   
}
```

Output:

[image]

Notice that, though the function was launched from the different threads, some portion of code got always executed always on the same context thread with ID: '5'.

But beware that, though all the web requests are executed on independent threads, they will eventually wait for some tasks to get executed on the singleton worker thread. This will eventually create a bottle neck in your web application. This is anyway your design limitation.

Comment: Is there a reason I should set the thread priority of the `contextThread` to Highest?

Comment: @jbb you can set any priority you like. I set it highest because the thread is responsible for executing some portion of code for all the other threads, so that other threads don't have to be waiting

Comment: one more thing `await _semaphore.WaitAsync(cancellationToken);` should be moved inside the `try` block.

Comment: By moving the `_semaphore.WaitAsync` inside the try block you risk to release the semaphore without acquiring it, in case of cancellation of the token. Which will cause unwanted parallelism.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Nice Catch! I got confused! May be that was the reason I placed it outside the try block for the first time

Comment: Great solution @zafar! I implemented it slightly differently and removed support for async calling (I'd like the WebAPI calls to always call it in a blocking manner).

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you could issue commands to the Junksoft API from a dedicated STA thread, using a [`BlockingCollection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.blockingcollection-1) class:

```
public class JunksoftSTA : IDisposable
{
    private readonly BlockingCollection<Action<Lazy<dynamic>>> _pump;
    private readonly Thread _thread;

    public JunksoftSTA()
    {
        _pump = new BlockingCollection<Action<Lazy<dynamic>>>();
        _thread = new Thread(() =>
        {
            var lazyApi = new Lazy<dynamic>(() =>
            {
                var powerShell = System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.Create();
                powerShell.AddScript("Add-Type -Path C:\Path\To\Junksoft.dll");
                powerShell.AddScript("New-Object Com.Junksoft.ScriptingObject");
                dynamic junksoftAPI = powerShell.Invoke()[0];
                return junksoftAPI;
            });
            foreach (var action in _pump.GetConsumingEnumerable())
            {
                action(lazyApi);
            }
        });
        _thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        _thread.IsBackground = true;
        _thread.Start();
    }

    public Task<T> CallAsync<T>(Func<dynamic, T> function)
    {
        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<T>(
            TaskCreationOptions.RunContinuationsAsynchronously);
        _pump.Add(lazyApi =>
        {
            try
            {
                var result = function(lazyApi.Value);
                tcs.SetResult(result);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                tcs.SetException(ex);
            }
        });
        return tcs.Task;
    }

    public Task CallAsync(Action<dynamic> action)
    {
        return CallAsync<object>(api => { action(api); return null; });
    }

    public void Dispose() => _pump.CompleteAdding();

    public void Join() => _thread.Join();
}
```

The purpose of using the [`Lazy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.lazy-1) class is for surfacing a possible exception during the construction of the dynamic object, by propagating it to the callers.

> ...exceptions are cached. That is, if the factory method throws an exception the first time a thread tries to access the `Value` property of the `Lazy<T>` object, the same exception is thrown on every subsequent attempt.

Usage example:

```
// A static field stored somewhere
public static readonly JunksoftSTA JunksoftStatic = new JunksoftSTA();

await JunksoftStatic.CallAsync(api => { api.Login("x", "y"); });
int age = await JunksoftStatic.CallAsync(api => api.GetAgeByCustomerId(custId));
```

In case you find that a single STA thread is not enough to serve all the requests in a timely manner, you could add more STA threads, all of them running the same code (`private readonly Thread[] _threads;` etc). The `BlockingCollection` class is thread-safe and can be consumed concurrently by any number of threads.

Comment: `CallAsync` is not purely asynchronous, because `_pump.Add` Will synchronously block the calling thread

Comment: @zafar the [`BlockingCollection.Add`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.blockingcollection-1.add) only blocks if a bounded capacity was specified when the `BlockingCollection` was initialized, until space is available to store the provided item. In my example I haven't specified a bounded capacity, although I probably should, to prevent an uncontrolled growth of the buffer in extreme usage scenarios.

Comment: Both this answer and zafar's answer are good and answer solve the problem! I picked zafar's answer becuase I found it a little bit more understandable but this solution might be better for you, depending on your experience!

Comment: @jbb kudos to zafar for offering the easiest to understand solution! :-)

Answer (score -1):

If you did not say that was a 3rd party tool, I would have asumed it is a GUI class. For practical reasons, it is a very bad idea to have multiple threads write to them. .NET enforces a strict "only the creating thread shall write" rule, from [2.0 onward](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14703806/3346583).

WebServers in general and ASP.Net in particular use a pretty big thread pool. We are talking 10's to 100's of Threads per Core. That means it is really hard to nail any request down to a specific Thread. You might as well not try.

Again, looking at the GUI classes might be your best bet. You could basically make a single thread with the sole purpose of immitating a GUI's Event Queue. The Main/UI Thread of your average Windows Forms application, is responsible for creating every GUI class instance. It is kept alive by polling/processing the event queue. It ends onlyx when it receies a cancel command, via teh Event Queue. Dispatching just puts orders into that Queue, so we can avoid Cross-Threading issues.