# What's the difference of using and not using Invoke?

Tags: c#, invoke

I'm confused with using and not using Invoke.

In the following example, I see no difference with

```
int answer = b(10, 10);
```

and

```
int answer = b.Invoke(10, 10);
```

so can anyone help me with this?
thx!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;

namespace TEST
{
    public delegate int BinaryOp(int x, int y);
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Main innvoked on thread {0}.", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
            BinaryOp b = new BinaryOp(add);
            //int answer = b(10, 10);      
            int answer = b.Invoke(10, 10); 

            Console.WriteLine("Doing more work in Main");
            Console.WriteLine("10 + 10 is {0}", answer);
            Console.Read();
        }

        static int add(int x, int y)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("add innvoked on thread {0}.", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
            return x + y;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: See this post: <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6888705/what-is-invoking>

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Func<T>() vs Func<T>.Invoke()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16309286/funct-vs-funct-invoke)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically there is no difference.

Specifically since a `Delegate` is not really a function rather a holder to a function, that class that holds the function has to have some way to Invoke it. Hence the method `Invoke`. On the other hand the compiler is smart enough to automatically call `Invoke` when you append parenthesis to a `Delegate`. See https://jacksondunstan.com/articles/3283.